# How do I fix this extremely slow MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

The purpose of this query is to list the distinct users someone has  connections to (ie. users that are followed by or are following the user with id 256 but excludes users who are either blocking or are blocked by the current user making the request (user with id 2)

The relationships table is pretty simple. The status column can be one of two values: "following" or "blocked":

```
mysql> describe relationships;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| follower_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| followee_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | varchar(191) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This query currently takes about 58 seconds to complete! User 256 only has 1500 connections. To put this is context, there are roughly 10,000 user rows, 5500 relationships rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.*, 
    -- "followed" is just a flag indicating if user #2 is currently following a given user
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `relationships`  
      WHERE `relationships`.`followee_id` = `users`.`id` 
        AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 2
    ) AS 'followed'
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `relationships` 
ON (
  (`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`follower_id` 
    AND `relationships`.`followee_id` = 256
  ) 
  OR (`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`followee_id` 
    AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 256
  )
)
WHERE `relationships`.`status` = 'following' 
  AND (
    -- Ensure we don't return users who are blocked by user #2 
    `users`.`id` NOT IN (
      SELECT `relationships`.`followee_id` 
      FROM `relationships` 
      WHERE `relationships`.`follower_id` = 2
        AND `relationships`.`status` = 'blocked'
    )
  )
  AND (
    -- Ensure we don't return users who are blocking user #2 
    `users`.`id` NOT IN (
      SELECT `relationships`.`follower_id` 
      FROM `relationships` 
      WHERE `relationships`.`followee_id` = 2 
        AND `relationships`.`status` = 'blocked'
    )
  )
ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Here's are the current indexes on `relationships`:

```
mysql> show index from relationships;
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                                                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| relationships |          0 | PRIMARY                                                       |            1 | id          | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          0 | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id |            1 | status      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          0 | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id |            2 | follower_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          0 | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id |            3 | followee_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          1 | index_relationships_on_followee_id                            |            1 | followee_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          1 | index_relationships_on_follower_id                            |            1 | follower_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          1 | index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id |            1 | status      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          1 | index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id |            2 | followee_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| relationships |          1 | index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id |            3 | follower_id | A         |        3002 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

explain results:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT `users`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `relationships` WHERE `relationships`.`followee_id` = `users`.`id` AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 2) AS 'followed' FROM `users` INNER JOIN `relationships` ON(`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`follower_id` AND `relationships`.`followee_id` = 256) OR (`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`followee_id` AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 256) WHERE `relationships`.`status` = 'following' AND (`users`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `relationships`.`followee_id` FROM `relationships` WHERE `relationships`.`follower_id` = 2 AND `relationships`.`status` = 'blocked')) AND (`users`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `relationships`.`follower_id` FROM `relationships` WHERE `relationships`.`followee_id` = 2 AND `relationships`.`status` = 'blocked')) ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 10;
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type        | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                     | key                                                                   | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                                                                                                            |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | relationships | index_merge | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id,index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id,index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id | index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id | 5,5     | NULL                          |    2 | Using union(index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | users         | ALL         | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                           | NULL                                                                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1534 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)                                                                                   |
|  4 | SUBQUERY           | relationships | ref         | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id,index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id,index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id         | 767     | const                         |    1 | Using where; Using index                                                                                                         |
|  3 | SUBQUERY           | relationships | ref         | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id,index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id,index_relationships_on_status_and_followee_id_and_follower_id | index_relationships_on_status_and_follower_id_and_followee_id         | 772     | const,const                   |    1 | Using where; Using index                                                                                                         |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | relationships | ref         | index_relationships_on_followee_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id                                                                                                                             | index_relationships_on_followee_id                                    | 5       | development.users.id |    1 | Using where                                                                                                                      |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Pls include the results of explain as well.

Comment: first thing - change type of column `status` from varchar to int or bit or enum

Comment: good point about the `status` column, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a concrete answer without testing this but I think this part of the query is the problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.*, (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `relationships`  
      WHERE `relationships`.`followee_id` = `users`.`id` 
        AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 2
    ) AS 'followed'
```

You're also using order by. Remove DISTINCT and order by and see if things speed up. I know it changes the query but I suspect that distinct is basically building a bunch of temporary tables and throwing them away for every row that it needs to check. Have a look here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Counts can be slow. make sure that the count is working from the fastest column. See this...

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

A good way to think about SQL is in SETS. Luckily MySQL supports sub queries.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Some pseudo SQL follows...

```
select user_id
from relationships as follower, relationships as followee
where ...
```

In the above we have two sets that we can then manipulate. Using sub queries this gets really interesting

```
select user_id
from (select user_id as f1 from relationships where ...) as follower, 
     (select user_id as f2 from relationships where ...) as followee
where ...
```

I've always found something like the above an easy way to think about self referencing tables.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I gave that a try and it seems you're on to something. 

When I removed the `DISTINCT` keyword the query took 3-5 seconds to complete instead of 58 seconds. 

Then I tried removing the order clause which resulted in the query taking only 0.05 seconds which didn't change when I added the `DISTINCT` keyword back into the query. 

So it seems like it's something to do with the order clause. The order is important because I'm using the id's as a pagination cursor.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in another query ie the order by would be done on the subset that DISTINCT produces.

Comment: Ok that works but now `DISTINCT` is adding up to an extra full second to the query. Queries are now between 0.5 seconds - 2 seconds with distinct and 0.2 seconds - 1 second without. Maybe there's a way to change the query so I don't get duplicates.

Comment: Think of SQL as set manipulation ie how do I minimize the set that this query produces. If any of the sub queries can be reduced try reducing them. I'll update my answer with an alternative way to think of self referencing tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell exactly how you should optimize your query and structure, first general hints:

1. use integers/bits/enums instead of varchars
2. use not null columns as much as possible
3. usually it makes sense to have unsigned columns (at least to have bigger range)
4. try different approaches to build query (check below)
5. distinct is quite expensive operation
6. sub-queries sometimes much faster neither joins

Anyway, I've prepared [sample fiddle with proposed optimizations](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58638/2), I've changed names of the columns to reduce confusion

final query could look like this:

```
select *
from users a
where
(
id in (select follower_id as id from relationships USE INDEX (user_id) where user_id = 256 and status = 'following')
or id in (select user_id from relationships USE INDEX (follower_id) where follower_id = 256 and status = 'following')
)
and id not in (select follower_id from relationships USE INDEX (user_id) where user_id = 2 and status = 'blocked')
and id not in (select user_id from relationships USE INDEX (follower_id) where follower_id = 2 and status = 'blocked')
```

though, it could be rewritten as follows:

```
select *
from users a
where
id in (select follower_id as id from relationships USE INDEX (user_id) where user_id = 256 and status = 'following'
    union all
    select user_id from relationships USE INDEX (follower_id) where follower_id = 256 and status = 'following')
and id not in (select follower_id from relationships USE INDEX (user_id) where user_id = 2 and status = 'blocked'
    union all
    select user_id from relationships USE INDEX (follower_id) where follower_id = 2 and status = 'blocked')
```

benchmark both, despite execution plan - actual performance may be different on real database

Comment: Thanks Lashane I'll try these out as well and see how they perform

Comment: Thanks for this Lashane, I've combined this with Harry's answer and the query is now able to complete in 0.05 seconds! Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, it optimizes poorly.  Instead, either use a `JOIN`, or `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )`.

The `OR` to `UNION` trick is good, but not if it is still inside `IN(...)`.

(To aid in readability, please omit the table name when there is only one table.  And rename `followee_id` and/or `follower_id`; they are too close to each other in spelling.)

Comment: Can you provide an example?